# How to use OAuth1.0 with HttpClient request

Tags: asp.net, .net, woocommerce

I am using HttpClient for the rest API calls on dotnet application, I am integrating WooCommerce. The problem I am facing is that my requests are getting fail due to reauthorization even though I am providing the key and secret on request.

Here is my code for GET endpoint:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("baseAddress");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var authHeaders = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth 1.0", $"consumer_key=jaksdhkasjd7as97d89hahkkzA5s consumer_secret= 89asjd9pasdaklsd09asdlaSkP909");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeaders;
var request = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("baseAddress" + "endpoint"), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, token);
```

On Postman its working fine:

[image: postman]